# LWJGL Keyboard loop

Tags: java, static, while-loop, lwjgl

I've created a static Input class, that basicly have a method that I can call, which is this:

```
public static boolean GetKeyDown(int keyCode) {
    while(Keyboard.next()) {
        Keyboard.enableRepeatEvents(false);
        if (Keyboard.getEventKeyState()) {
            if (Keyboard.getEventKey() == keyCode) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And in my game update loop, I've wanted to use this, instead of having to make a single while-loop:

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S)) {
    //Something happens
}
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R)) {
    //Something happens
}
//etc..
```

But it seems that only the first one loaded, will work. In this case 'S'. Is there a way for me to do be able to use the others too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because in your `GetKeyDown()` method, you call `Keyboard.next()`, when you call that method it removes the `Event` of the current key from `Keyboard`, the only gets refilled with Events, when you call `Display.update();`

> NOTE: This method does not query the operating system for new events. To do that, Display.processMessages() (or Display.update()) must be called first.

Source: [LWJGL Docs](http://www.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/input/Keyboard.html#poll())

#### You Could

Instead you can use the [Keyboard.isKeyDown(int key)](http://www.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/input/Keyboard.html#isKeyDown(int)) method, to achieve what you're trying to do.

Though it returns true/false depending on the following.

> Returns: true if the key is down according to the last poll()

But that still doesn't quite fix the problem because it relies on the `poll()` method.

#### Fixing The Problem

You can fix the problem by creating some custom methods to use with the `Keyboard` class, as you already did, though as said the Keyboard Events only gets updated when you call the `Display.update();` method.

You already got the right idea about which function to create, though you need to split them into, two different methods. You need a secondary method which you call once each time you want to update your keyboard.

```
public class MyKeyboard {
    /*
     * Remember that the index where we store the value,
     * is the index of the key. Thereby one key might have
     * an index of 400, then your array need to have at least
     * the same size, to be able to store it.
     */
    public static boolean[] keys = new boolean[100]; // 100 is the amount of keys to remember!

    public static void update() {
        while(Keyboard.next()) {
            if (Keyboard.getEventKey() < keys.length) {
                keys[Keyboard.getEventKey()] = Keyboard.getEventKeyState();
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean isKeyDown(int key) {
        if ((key > 0) && (key < keys.length)) {
            return keys[key];
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Remember to only call the `MyKeyboard.update()` method once per `Display.update()` I also renamed your `GetKeyDown()` method to `isKeyDown()`, *because I think that sounds and describes it better, but you can rename it again in your project if you want to.*

*The above code was made within this answer, without the use of an IDE, etc. So if there's anything wrong with it I apologize, but just comment and I will fix it.*

One problem that arises with this method is the lack of rechecking.  Since `Keyboard.next()` only checks the inputs that have occurred in the current frame.  A button which was once pressed will remain "pressed" until it is pressed again.  I ran into this problem while trying to implement this solution.  The answer to this new problem is here:

```
public static void update() {

    for(int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        keys[i] = false;
    }
    while(Keyboard.next()) {
        keys[Keyboard.getEventKey()] = Keyboard.getEventKeyState();
    }
}
```

You must clear the keypresses of the previous frame by setting everything to false.